# I have an angle that changes based on player input using lerp, but it doesnt lerp when the target is zero

Tags: lua, love2d

This few lines of code apply 25 degrees to the players rotation by using the x_value it either gives 1,0 or -1, it works fine if I am pressing left or right but when I let go the player.target_value should be set to 0, which it is from my debugging but it doesn't lerp to 0 making the player stay in its previous angle, I have scratched my head for a few moments and I cant figure it out why it doesn't change, I could be missing something completely but I have no clue.

```
  -- Check if the player is moving along the x axis, if not we set its angle to 0
  if x_value ~= 0 then
    -- Check if the target angle has changed
    if player.target_angle ~= 25 * x_value then
      player.target_angle = 25 * x_value
      player.target_angle_changed = true
    end
  else
    -- if the player isnt moving left or right set angle to zero and angle changed to true
    player.target_angle = 0
    player.target_angle_changed = true
  end

  -- Check if the target angle has changed
  if player.target_angle_changed then
    progress = 0
    player.target_angle_changed = false
  else
    -- if the target angle has not changed we start moving the value with progress + dt
    progress = math.min(progress + dt / duration, 1)
  end

  -- Apply the rotation to the player with lerp
  player.angle = lerp(player.angle, player.target_angle, progress)

  -- DEBUG to see the progress
  value = "Target_Value: " .. player.target_angle .. " Player_Angle" .. player.angle
```

The lerp function:

```
function lerp(a, b, t)
  return a + (b - a) * t
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not moving, you set `target_angle_changed = true`.

if `player.target_angle_changed` you set `progress = 0`.

When progress is zero, lerp only uses the first input, which is the previous angle. Therefore, when you are not moving, you do not change the angle.

I need more context for a solution, but right now it's definitely not what you want.